# Assembly (with Nasm): Invalid effective address error

Tags: assembly, nasm

So, I'm writing an assembly program where I print a message to the screen, but I'm having a bit of an issue.

Admitting my assembly knowledge is lackluster, searching around doesn't seem to be providing an answer, so I was hoping for more insight from you guys.

My program looks like this:

```
section .text

main:

    mov ebx, message
    mov ecx, 0xb8000

readloop:

    mov ecx, [bl]
    inc ecx
    mov ecx, 0x1f
    inc ebx
    inc ecx
    cmp ebx, 0
    jne readloop
    hlt

section .data

    message: db "Words to be read", 0
```

The `mov ecx, [bl]` line is what's giving me the error, but I don't understand why. To my (limited) knowledge it shouldn't be causing me issues.

Anyone able to help out with this?

Comment: Like `nasm`says, `[bl]` is not a valid effective address. Refer to the section _"Addressing-Mode Encoding of ModR/M and SIB Bytes"_ in volume 2 of [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals) for a table of valid effective address forms.

Comment: To state the obvious, addresses are 32-bit values in 32-bit mode, so your address reference on that line must be a 32-bit value, e.g. `[ebx]`.